# Integral $\int \frac{x\,dx}{(a-bx^2)^2} $

Tags: integration

How can I integrate
$$
\int \frac{x\,dx}{(a-bx^2)^2}
$$ I've tried to use partial fraction decomposition, but I'm getting six equations for four variables, and they don't give uniform answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $u=a-bx^2$ so your integral is $-\frac{1}{2b}\int\frac{du}{u^2}=\frac{1}{2bu}+C$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{x\,dx}{(a-bx^2)^2}=-\frac{1}{2b}\int \frac{(-2bx)\,dx}{(a-bx^2)^2}=-\frac1{2b}\int \frac{d(a-bx^2)}{(a-bx^2)^2}=\frac{1}{2b(a-bx^2)}+c$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b} \sin \theta \implies dx=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}\cos \theta d\theta$ to get $$\frac{1}{ab}\int\tan \theta \cdot \sec^2\theta \ d\theta =\frac {1}{ab}\int\tan\theta \ d(\tan\theta) = \frac {1}{2ab}\tan^2\theta+C\\=\frac{1}{2ab} \frac{\sin^2\theta}{1-\sin^2\theta}+C\\=\frac{1}{2ab} \frac{\frac ba x^2}{1-\frac ba x^2}+C \\ =\frac{x^2}{2a(a-bx^2)} +C$$